# Creating App Package through Command Line in WinRT

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-8, windows-runtime

How can I create, WinRT App package through command line. What i am trying to achieve is, By executing a .BAT file i need to build and create app package of my windows 8 application(.sln). I build the source code using msbuild command. But i don't know how to create app package using command. Anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

Running msbuild command on the project should both build the project and generate the packages.